# What is the structure of the MLP's input?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-mining

Each complex number, component of either an input or an output pattern, is associated
with two adjacent neurons of the MLP input or output layer respectively, having its real part assigned to the left neuron of the pair and its imaginary part to the right one.

1) What's the meaning of "its real part assigned to the left neuron of the pair and its imaginary part to the right one"?

2) How to handle complex number as the input of neural network , how to train? Do I still use the fully connected neural network?

Comment: This sentence is so crystal clear, I don't even know what to explain. I suggest you study the basis (either of complex numbers, neural networks, or both).

Comment: I did not see a realPart--->Imaginarypart as a neuron. Would you explain this structure of MLP for me ?

Comment: See my answer. There is no "realPart--->Imaginarypart" neuron. There's 2 neurons which take i and r respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is a complex Number n=(r,i) with r= real part, i= imaginary part.

```
Input layer with 2 nodes: (r,i)
Hidden layer: Specifics (size) unknown from your text. Try size 2-4
Output layer with 2 nodes: (r,i)
```

You input a complex number, you get a complex number as an output.
Training is as usual. The network is simply approximating a function within the space of complex numbers. The complex number is simply treated as two different numbers which are inputted. There's nothing special here. Just a neural network with input layer size 2.

Edit:

Example: 
a + bi is inputted to the network. 
-> input node 1 receives: a, input node 2 receives: b 
-> output node 1 gives: f(a), output node 2 gives: f(b)